# Choosing the right EC2 instance for three NodeJS Applications

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

I'm running three MEAN stack programmes. Each application receives over 10,000 monthly users. Could you please assist me in finding an EC2 instance for my apps?

I've been using a "t3.large" instance with two vCPUs and eight gigabytes of RAM, but it costs $62 to $64 per month.

I need help deciding which EC2 instance to use for three Nodejs applications.

Answer (score 1):

First check CloudWatch metrics for the current instances. Is CPU and memory usage consistent over time? Analysing the metrics could help you to decide whether you should select a smaller/bigger instance or not.

One way to avoid too unnecessary costs is to use auto scaling groups and load balancers. By using them and finding and applying proper settings, you could have always right amount of computing power for your applications.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/working_with_metrics.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/auto-scaling-groups.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think it would be better to check the CloudWatch metrics and then choose instance depending on the usage of the current instance.

Comment: That would be a decent solution if the CPU and memory usage are not changing significantly over time. If they are changing (for example there are a lot of idle hours during a day or night) you will be paying for unused resources. 

And if you don't want to use auto scaling, load balancing would be still something you would want to use to distribute the traffic evenly.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your applications. If your apps need more compute power or more memory or more storage? Deciding a server is similar to installing an app on system. Check what are basic requirements for it & then proceed to choose server.

If you have 10k+ monthly customers, think about using ALB so that traffic gets distributed evenly. Try caching to server some content if possible. Use unlimited burst mode of t3 servers if CPU keeps hitting 100%. Also, try to optimize code so that fewer resources are consumed. Once you are comfortable with ec2 choice, try to purchase saving plans or RIs for less cost.

Also, do monitor the servers & traffic using Cloudwatch agent, internet monitor etc features.

Comment: I think it would be better for now to check the CloudWatch metrics and then choose instance depending on the usage of the current instance.